How to set 'External website' component of Power Apps Form to an existing value in my Dataverse table?
I have a database column named 'clientUrl'.
In the Form, I want to add a component for External website however it asks for a static site url. How can I set its value to be the clientUrl from my Database?

You could add a column to your Dataverse table of type Single line of text → URL
Then this column can be added to your entity's main form:

The user can click the globe icon on the right to open the link.
I haven't made the column read-only in the pic above. This way we can add whatever URL we want, save the form, and the URL will be saved in the Dataverse record.
.
If your database is an external one, I'd suggest looking into virtual tables (entities). After you map the external database table to the Dataverse one, you could use the URL column type again.
